# How to install two apps developed with React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

friends!

I am facing a big problem while developing a React-native(expo) project and I need your help. I have created APK_Prob and APK_Deb installation files for my project and I want to install both of them on a single device. However, they are being recognized as the same app and being updated as one app, which is causing issues for me. Do you know how I can resolve this problem?

Create two APK files from a single project and run two apps on a single device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apps are recognized by its bundle identifier. So if you want to install multiple apps on the same device, make sure the bundle identifiers are different.